# How to set unqualified for an element whose parent is schema in xsd

Tags: xml, api, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am working on an API project. I have 2 xsd files.

wsdl file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"

    xmlns:tns="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer"
    xmlns:cns="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons"
    name="uTransfer" 
    targetNamespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer">
    
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Imports">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons" schemaLocation="Commons.xsd" />
            <xsd:import namespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer" schemaLocation="uTransfer.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="RefererLoginSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RefererLoginRequest">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="RefererLoginSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="paramaters" element="tns:RefererLoginResponse" >
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message> 
    <!-- @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Port Type -->
    

    <wsdl:portType name="uTransfer">
        <wsdl:operation name="RefererLogin">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:RefererLoginSoapIn">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:RefererLoginSoapOut">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        
    </wsdl:portType>
    
    
    <!-- @@@@@ binding -->
    
    <wsdl:binding name="uTransferSOAP" type="tns:uTransfer">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>      
        <wsdl:operation name="RefererLogin">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.umonitor.com/Authenticate/RefererLogin" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>    
    </wsdl:binding>
    
    <wsdl:service name="uTransfer">
        <wsdl:port name="uTransferSOAP" binding="tns:uTransferSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://uat.umonitor.com/utransferapi/services/uTransfer"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    
</wsdl:definitions>
```

utransfer.xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cmn="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons" xmlns:tns="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer"
    targetNamespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons"
        schemaLocation="Commons.xsd">
    </xs:import>

    <xs:element name="RefererLoginRequest" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Key" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Id" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="UserInfo" form="unqualified" type="cmn:PersonType" />
                <xs:element name="BankAccounts" form="unqualified" type="cmn:BankAccountsType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="RefererLoginResponse">  
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Response" type="cmn:ResponseType" form="unqualified"/>
                <xs:element name="TOSContentURL" type="xs:string" form="unqualified"/>
                <xs:element name="SessionKey" type="xs:string" form="unqualified"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Commons.xsd file:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons" targetNamespace="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer/Commons"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xs:complexType name="PersonType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="MiddleName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="EmailAddress" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    
    <xs:complexType name="ResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ResponseCode" type="xs:int" form="unqualified" />
            <xs:element name="ResponseDescription" type="xs:string" form="unqualified"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BankAccountType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AccountId" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="RoutingNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Institution" type="InstitutionType" />
            <xs:element name="NameOnAccount" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="AccountNickName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="AccountAuthStatus" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BankAccountsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="BankAccount" type="BankAccountType"
                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

THese are my files. Now the problem I have is the prefix namespace. For example,  response for login request comes as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <utr:RefererLoginResponse xmlns:utr="http://xml.umonitor.com/uTransfer">
         <Response>
            <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
            <ResponseDescription>Request processed successfully</ResponseDescription>
         </Response>
         <SessionKey>abcd</SessionKey>
 
      </utr:RefererLoginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem I have is the prefix namespace for RefererLoginResponse. In the above response, it is coming as utr:RefererLoginResponse. I need the response without utr. I tried giving elementFormDefault as unqualified and qualified. But that is not providing a solution. I need the LoginRequest as qualified, meaning with namespace prefix and all the other fields without namespace prefix, that is unqualified. THat is why I have given elementFormDefault="qualified" in utransfer.xsd and then mentioned all the fields as unqualified. Please help to fix this issue. What I actually want is to set like this in utransfer.xsd, which is not possible.

<xs:element name="RefererLoginResponse" form="unqualified">

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the element declaration in a different schema document, with a different (or no) `targetNamespace`, and then connect the two schema documents with an `xs:import` declaration.

Global element declarations are always in the targetNamespace of the schema.

Comment: I am looking for a minimal change. There are a lot of requests and responses. So separating the files in my last option.